# Concurrent and In Order Downloading chunks from 2 servers - Android

Tags: java, android, concurrency, chunks

I am working on an Android app which purpose is to **download chunks**(parts of a video file) from 2 servers, **append them in order**(into a main video file) after each one is downloaded and finally **play this video file** while downloading continues..

This works well when downloading is done serial by using two different threads(one for each server) that perform downloading. I want to know how it is possible to achieve the above but with concurrent downloading, instead of serial.

That is to download chunks from servers at the same time and in order. For example, **for the same period of time** download chunk0, chunk1 & chunk2 from server1 (which let's say is 3 times faster than server2) and chunk3 from server2, so that we totally use all the available bandwidth of the 2 servers at this period of time. And this process repeats until all chunks are downloaded.

By using threads and join, downloading is serial, as i said above. In order to make it concurrent, i tried to remove join from each thread, but then it doesn't download chunks in order and also download only from one server, not from both. AsyncTask is not a solution, as it also doesn't download chunks in order.

So, is there any way to achieve this **concurrent** and **in order** downloading of chunks as I described it above? Has anyone done something like this as a project, so as to know an answer for sure?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the popular technique among download accelerators.

In general, the idea is about requesting chunks from each server using the Range HTTP header. (The server responds the Accept-Ranges header when it is capable of processing the Range header accordingly). ([This blog has a good explanation about that](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/)).

Every thread/runnable/callable has to know which chunk is its responsibility ( first byte position + length ?) because each one will have to write its own part in the file.

Then there will be a decision to be made, you can:

1. Write the file using an instance of [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in each thread, obviously positioning the file pointer in the first byte position of its chunk (with the [seek method](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29)), or..
2. Be sure that you have a unique worker thread (see [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) and [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29)) that is in charge of writing the bytes told by each thread. As in the moment of writing, you will use seek to move the file pointer into the correct position, there will be no errors of overlapping.

NOTE: If you want to be able to start the playback when you have your first chunk, you may do it by executing that code after the first chunk thread download+write has finished.